# What is this multiplexer doing in this design?

Tags: fpga, clock, xilinx, multiplexer

The design is from a [Xilinx FPGA doc](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/data_sheets/4000.pdf). I think these are preprogrammed look up tables because there is no select bit input, but on the bottom it says they are:

> Multiplexer[s] Controlled by Configuration Program

I'm not sure how to interpret that. The design sort of looks like an edge detector.

What is this and what is it doing?

[image]

Is it configurable to have the same functionality of these two circuits?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Multiplexer controlled by configuration program" is a reference to how FPGA's work.

This multiplexer is not really part of your design. It's part of the configuration logic. Your design would instantiate a flip flop, either rising edge triggered or falling edge triggered(i.e: "if rising_edge(clk)" OR "if falling_edge(clk)", and the mux is the piece of logic that implements that.

The select input to the MUX that you don't see in the diagram is a single bit in the configuration bitstream that gets loaded/configured at power up.

Beyond that, there is no edge detection going on with the MUX. A MUX has no memory. In synchronous design, Edge detection requires 1 Bit of memory (i.e: the previous state: rising_edge_a <= a AND NOT previous_a). The Mux selects either an inverted or non-inverted clock to feed to the inherently rising or falling edge triggered(one or the other I'm not sure which) Flip Flop.

Comment: Great answer. That actually cleared it up perfectly. I know in VHDL I can specify if the process should occur on a rising edge and I completely forgot about it until you mentioned it just now. So that is how the FPGA implements that part. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

It looks like it allows the output flip-flop to be triggered by either the rising or falling edge of K (the clock signal), as selected by how you configure the multiplexer.

Comment: It is a configurable edge detector... what is the benefit of that?

Comment: It's no edge detector. It's selecting if your FF is triggered by positive (rising) or negative (falling) edge.

Comment: @Paebbels Maybe I'm using the wrong terminology. I thought [this was an edge detector](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electronic/ietron/edge.gif). Is this the effect? A resulting short pulse, based on the configuration.

Comment: To your edit: No, your circuits use AND gates, but the FPGA has a multiplexer. That's a switch or as equation: \$y = \bar{s}a + sb\$